How technically and legally sell FOSS software with commercial license?
I found this question here:
Can I sell personal/commercial licenses for an Open Source product? With answer about QT library that sell commercial license to companies.
I want to do the same, I want to make my project AGPL, but allow anybody to buy commercial license if they don't want to make their whole code Open Source.
So the question how this works technically? If the work is on AGPL, and I have contributors do I need to have permission from those contributors to sell the project with commercial license? And how this will look technically? Should I just remove all license information from my source code and change LICENSE file?
Do I need to have CLA in order to sell the code with a different license?
I hope I can ask two questions, I basically what to know how commercial license to AGPL project works, and if it's even possible.

The Qt people are able to do this because they are the sole rightsholders in Qt, and so may unilaterally choose to convey it to others on any terms they choose.
As you're using (or intending to use) contributions licensed to you under AGPL, you do not have this unilateral right.  In order to do what you want, you will need to ensure that those contributors give you that right.  This could indeed take the form of a CLA that permitted arbitrary relicensing.
If you can get these rights, you'll need to erase any mention of the AGPL from your proprietary-licensed offering.  It's good form to keep all copyright notices, including your contributors', but that as long as you have their CLAs permitting you to relicense, that's not an obstacle.  You can then convey copies to paying end-users with a licence that permits the use of your code in their proprietary product, on such terms as you desire.
Whether this will discourage contributions, I cannot say for certain.

Where does the requirement to erase all mentions of the AGPL come from? A commercial client will have a contract in hand which explicitly trumps whatever license is mentioned in the source files, and they can still exercise their rights under the AGPL if they want to (e.g. to redistribute derived works).

It's not so much a requirement as a really good idea.  A commercial client paying for a non-copyleft version of the software, which they can use in their proprietary code, won't be very happy to see AGPL headers plastered all over it, as those call into question the licensing status of what they've bought.  And no, the contract wouldn't automatically trump eg the AGPLv3, since any restrictive terms would fall foul of s7.  The best one could say is that the two sets of terms were of equal priority, and the courts would need to sort out the winner - which, again, commercial clients don't love.

@TooTea important detail: that commercial contract can only trump the license if both are/would be granted by the same entity, or when the license allows that (which many don't). Here the first is the case so it works

@Hobbamok Well, if you have the right to remove all the license notices from the files (such as when you're the copyright owner, which is almost certainly the case if you're selling commercial software), you aren't restricted by the terms of the license in the first place and can just grant a different (commercial) license that grants the customer additional rights (such as the right to do whatever they want regardless of what the AGPL says).

@TooTea - YOU might know that you bought the program under different licence, but what about five years down the line, when the people looking at it are completely different. They might not have a clue of where you got it and suddenly there is a potential legal problem because you didn't remove licence files that do not pertain the licence you actually have. It's just overall a bad idea.

@Madhatter: A license is nothing more but permission by the copyright holder to do certain things. Two licenses means you have two sets of permissions. There is no precedence. If license A allows it, it is allowed. If license B allows it, it is allowed. If neither allows it, it is not allowed.

@gnasher729 if, however, license A explicitly forbids something, and license B explicitly permits that thing, what then?  Thus, the discussion about priority.

"the contract wouldn't automatically trump eg the AGPLv3" - Perhaps true, but only the rightsholder has standing to sue over violating the license.  If every rightsholder is party to a contract which provides such licensing, such a lawsuit would violate the contract (assuming any licensing component of the contract was not terminated).  I've also seen dual-licensed products where the license included both licenses as well as an explanation as to which would apply...though as a buyer I found this incredibly irritating.

@MadHatter: Licenses can't forbid things.  All they can do is fail to grant permission (possibly by making permission conditional on not doing things the licensor wishes to forbid).  If License A explicitly forbids something, license B takes priority (because the user has not been granted license A).

@Brian and in this case, the licence is AGPL (which actual lawyers say is a contract) and the other document is a contract of sale.  So you might well have a point in a different situation, but not, I think, in this one.

@MadHatter, ...if the only other document is a sale contract, as opposed to having a sale contract and a separate commercial license such that the former entitles one to the latter, that's sloppy lawyering.
